# Is there a way to see the RenderTreeBuilder version of the razor file in blazor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5

Take the index page for example:

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

It is my understanding that this will be translated into some code using the RenderTreeBuilder which may look something like this:

```
builder.OpenElement(0, "h1")
builder.AddContent(1, "Hello, world!")
.
.
.
```

Is there a place where I can inspect the RenderTreeBuilder version of the razor pages?
I would like to start trying out RenderTreeBuilder and would like to know how it is done, for references purposes.

Apologies in advanced if this is a duplicate. I will delete this question if so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The BlazorMarkup is translated into C# files that are using the RenderTreeBuilder. It is comparable to what WPF does when it comes to XAML and C# files.

After you have built your project, go to the `obj/debug/net5.0/Razor/`.

Keep in mind to use a debug build. Otherwise, you won't see the files.

[image: Content of the razor directory]

You will see the same directory structure as in your project. Directories are listed as long as they contain razor files. Open the file, e.g., Index.razor.g.cs (.g stands for generated), and you can see the calls to `RenderTreeBuilder`

```
 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/")]
    public partial class Index : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>\r\n\r\nWelcome to your new app.\r\n\r\n");
            __builder.OpenComponent<BlazorApp1.Shared.SurveyPrompt>(1);
            __builder.AddAttribute(2, "Title", "How is Blazor working for you?");
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
    }
```

Comment: I can not see this folder for .Net 6. Is there a way to see build files for .net 6 also?

Comment: I think I found it. For .net => https://stackoverflow.com/a/70968184/2178028